Hume's simplest ideas
I'm reading "Enquiry concerning human understanding", and it's not very clear for me if Hume was allowing that the ideas of objects could be reduced to the ideas of sensations.
I know that his successors were surely allowing that. But how about Hume himself?
Because, from what I read, it's really hard to tell. For the corresponding excerpts from his works I'll be grateful in double.

According to his famous bundle theory, obviously the ideas of objects could be reduced to the ideas of sensations...

"This resemblance gives us a propension to consider these interrupted perceptions as the same; and also a propension to connect them by a continu'd existence... Here then we have a propensity to feign the continu'd existence of all sensible objects; and as this propensity arises from some lively impressions of the memory, it bestows a vivacity on that fiction." T 1.4.2.42. Objects are not reduced to perceptions alone, but to them combined with our "propensity of imagination" to assimilate resemblances.

For commentary, see Inukai, Perceptions and Objects:"The bodies that Hume affirms are, at bottom, no different from perceptions, but they can be distinguished from merely internal perceptions like pain or pleasure in terms of their "different relations, connexions, and durations" (T 1.2.6.9)...  Hume must... affirm only the existence of perceptions, sometimes conceived as internally existing and mind-dependent and sometimes conceived as existing outside and independent of the mind."
